# CDK constructs: passing values to constructors vs using the context values

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I wrote a small cdk construct that parses the logs in a cloudwatch log group via a lambda and sends a mail when a pattern is matched. This allows a developer to be notified via an sns topic, should an error appear in the logs.

The construct needs to know which log group to monitor, and which pattern to look for. These are currently passed in as parameters to its constructor. The user of my small construct library is supposed to use this construct as part of his stack. However, one could also define them as parameters, or [better yet given what the docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html) values in a context - basically using this construct in a standalone app.

Would this be an appropriate use of the context? What else it is useful for?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say a definitive answer, but I would recommend always passing in properties to a construct explicitly on the constructor.

A) This creates consistency with the rest of the constructs.

B) Nothing is 'hidden' in your construct definition.

The only thing I've generally found context useful for is passing in parameters from the CLI, but even that is pretty rare and there are often better ways to do it.